# What is the structure in which people sit on the elephant called in English?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What is the structure in which people sit on the elephant called in English?

Here is a picture which describes exactly what I mean. The structure here is in silver color, and has three people on it.

n.b. I don't know the name of it even in my native language.

[image]

Comment: I would call it a "structure in which people sit on an elephant," or something like that.

Answer (score 33):

To the best of my knowledge, it's called a **howdah**.

> "**howdah**: a seat or covered pavilion on the back of an elephant or camel"

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/howdah

Please bear in mind that this is not originally an English word, but a [Persian / Urdu / Arabic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=howdah) one. However, as with much of English, rather than come up with our own words for foreign objects, we simply borrowed the local term for it and assimilated it into the English language.

Comment: Thank you^, but this is a Persian / Urdu / Arabic word.   see here: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=howdah

Comment: Thank you - other than English, I'd only heard this word used in Hindi. Have updated my answer to include your information.

Comment: As a footnote, these are called [*loanwords*](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/loanwordterm.htm), and English has quite a few of them, including [several of Hindi/Urdu origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Hindi_or_Urdu_origin)

Comment: There really isn't much point in having an actual word for it in English. It's not like the average Brit ever sees/saw one of these unless he/she happens to live in one of the former colonies.

Comment: @Industrious The fact that the word originated in another language does not mean it's not the correct English word. Many common English words have etymological origins in other languages.

Comment: @J.R.: It wouldn't be too much of an exaggeration to say that English IS a bunch of loan words :-)

Comment: @jamesqf - Indeed. As [has been commented before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Nicoll#.22The_Purity_of_the_English_Language.22), "We don't just borrow words; on occasion, English has pursued other languages down alleyways to beat them unconscious and riffle their pockets for new vocabulary".

Comment: @barbecue: Industrious meant that this is a Persian / Urdu / Arabic word rather than a *Hindi* one (as this answer claimed at the time). I don't think (s)he was arguing that it's therefore not English.

Comment: note for English learners: in the Nicoll quote, [_riffle_ is a typo](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/rec.arts.sf-lovers/5tQFnNbvN80/kzZPphkck00J), and should be [_rifle_](http://www.wordnik.com/words/rifle), "to search with intent to steal; to ransack, pillage or plunder".

Comment: There is a book written in Kamrupi dialect of Assamese language called _Dontal Hatir Une Khowda Howda_ by [Indira Goswami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamoni_Raisom_Goswami). The translated English version's name is [The Moth Eaten Howdah of the Tusker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moth_Eaten_Howdah_of_the_Tusker).

Comment: This is certainly reminiscent of what if carried by footmen would be called a *palanquin*, although here it’s really just a *platform*.

Answer (score 13):

It is called a [*howdah*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/howdah).

> **howdah** - noun
>
> (in South Asia) a seat for riding on the back of an elephant or camel, typically with a canopy and accommodating two or more people.

Oxford Living Dictionary

[Wikipedia: Howdah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howdah)